# Find all the values of $\theta$ that satisfy $\cos(x \theta ) + \cos( (x+2) \theta ) = \cos( \theta )$

Tags: proof-verification, trigonometry

> Find all the values of $\theta$ that satisfy the equation 
>   $$\cos(x \theta ) + \cos( (x+2) \theta ) = \cos( \theta )$$

I've tried simplifying with factor formulae and a combo of compound angle formulae, and I'm still stuck. I get to $\theta = 180^\circ$ and $\theta = \frac{60^\circ}{x+1}$, but I'm unsure if that's correct.

It seems to work for $\theta=180^\circ$, but I can't verify the other solution. I feel as though it should be a numerical solution, but I'm unsure.

Comment: Is $x$ supposed to be an integer or any number?

Comment: Great question. The question on the national examination is exactly as I posted it. Granted, the questions on the national examination in this country are riddled with mistakes, hence my reservations about my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's $$2\cos(x+1)\theta\cos\theta=\cos\theta$$ or
$$(2\cos(x+1)\theta-1)\cos\theta=0.$$
Can you end it now?

Actually, $\cos\theta=0$ gives
$$\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi k,$$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Also, there is a mistake in your second sequence.

I used $$\cos\alpha+\cos\beta=2\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}$$ and
$$\pi=180^{\circ}.$$

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you got the formula? Also as a side note to the author of the question, it is unclear whether or not you are familiar with radians, so please note that $180° = \pi $rad.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 0):

Use
$$\cos(p)+\cos(q)=2 \cos \left(\frac{p+q}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{p-q}{2}\right)$$ Make $p=(x+2)\theta$ and $q=x\theta$ making your problem to be
$$2\cos((x+1)\theta) \cos(\theta)= \cos(\theta)$$ and then the two cases.